# Are there problems known to be not in $P$ but not known to be outside $NP$?

Tags: computational-complexity

Although most experts believe that $NP$ is not equal to $P$, for a long time I believed that of the two directions of attacking the $P$ vs $NP$ problem trying to prove that $P = NP$ is the more fun one as it can be resolved by finding a clever algorithm, while showing $P \neq NP$ requires some abstract reasoning to show that certain problems cannot possibly be solved by *any* polynomial time algorithm.

Today it dawned on me however that other people have already done the abstract reasoning showing some problems outside $P$ and hence one actually *might* be able to show that $P \neq NP$ (provided it's true) by constructing an algorithm. Just take one of the known 'non-$P$' problems and show that it is in $NP$ by cooking up a certificate for it as well as an polynomial time algorithm that verifies it.

Although I have no plans of wasting my time carrying out this scheme, I *am* curious if there are any known problems for which one might try it. That is: are there any problems known not to be in $P$ but not known to be outside $NP$?

Comment: http://www.icm2014.org/en/awards/prizes/NevanlinnaPrizeWinner

Comment: Thanks for the link! I can't play sound now so I'll have to play the video later, but I looked up the unique games conjecture on Wikipedia. What is not clear to me: do you mean that some (or all?) problems about which the UGC states that they are NP hard are examples of the type of problem I am asking for in the question? Or perhaps that UCG would imply that under assumption of P != NP?

Comment: Just that, in the absence of a resolution of P vs. NP, there is progress on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $\:$ The [EXPTIME-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME) problems are such problems.

More generally, for every [time-constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function#Time-constructible_definitions) function f in $\:$n^[$(\omega(1))$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) $\cap$ 2^(n^(O(1)))$\:$, $\:$ the problem "Does the [Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) M halt within f(number_of_states_in_(M)) steps?"

is not in P but not known to be outside NP.

Comment: According to the page you linked these are known to be outside $NP$ and thus don't answer the question.

Comment: Where does it claim that? $\;$

Comment: nevermind I read it wrong, it says the $NEXPTIME$ complete problems are not in $NP$, my apologies.